# "unnamed package not allowed in module"

Tags: java, java-module

So I am trying to create a calculator that calculates the new price of a product after its 20% discount.

This is the code that I have typed, and the following is the description of my error

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double old_price;
        double new_price;
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("What is the original price of your product");
        
        new_price = old_price*(1+0.2);
        System.out.println("The price after our discount is" +new_price);
        
        
        
        
    }

}

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\ceyze\eclipse-workspace\SalePriceCalculator\bin
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: project.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
```

Comment: just google "unnamed package not allowed in module" or "xxx.class found in top-level directory ".faster than asking questions.

Comment: This has exactly nothing to do with your import of `java.util.Scanner`. Read the error message.

Comment: You've set up the java project to use jigsaw modules. Don't do that - it's not widely adopted and brings various complications. One of them is that all classes __must__ be in a package and your `project` class is not. You could put it in a package, but simpler to kill the 9-headed hydra by piercing it through the heart, than lopping one head off: Don't make it a jigsaw module based project.

Comment: In addition, don't leave `// TODO` comments like that from your IDE littered around your code, and don't use `double` for monetary values.